# When I switch workspace all workspaces are merged

Tags: 12.04, windows, workspaces, browser

When I switch workspaces it looks like all workspaces are "merged" into one workspace and then they re split again. This would be no problem if it weren't for the fact that all my browser windows get stuck on workspace 1 after the "merge". Is there any way to stop this behavior? The workspace switching is also significantly slower in 12.04 than 11.10. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: can you provide a screenshot? :)

Comment: Perhaps this is related to your issue? [How to prevent applications from separate workspaces all landing on a single workspace when docking back into docking-station](http://askubuntu.com/questions/251344/how-to-prevent-applications-from-separate-workspaces-all-landing-on-a-single-wor) ?

Comment: Question is about 12.04 which is EOL. OP hasn't signed on for 5+ years and never responded to comment 4+ years ago. VTC as `not reproducible``