# How to prevent applications from separate workspaces all landing on a single workspace upon a (un)docking event or when connecting a beamer via VGA?

Tags: 12.04, compiz, workspaces, vga, docking

Now that finally [docking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119264/how-to-undock-ibm-thinkpad-x41-from-x4-docking-station-successfully) seems to be *fully* supported on my system, hurray!, I can address a *relatively* minor issue (or even a [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) ?):

Normally, I have (all) four workspaces populated with my standard applications. Whenever I dock back into my docking-station (e.g. from standby-mode), all the open applications from separate workspaces land on a single -- the one "active" whilst re-docking -- workspace.

"Fixing" that, i.e., getting my stuff back in the correct order and every application back into its respective and pre-ordained workspace, takes me about 5 - 10 seconds, so I *can* live with that... but clearly it's sub-ideal.

Any comments & help much appreciated.

**Edit / Addendum**

This also occurs when connecting an external monitor / beamer / projector (via VGA).

**Edit 2**

Related (and possibly related) posts:

- [Workspace stays fixed on external monitor when switching workspace](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76995/workspace-stays-fixed-on-external-monitor-when-switching-workspace) (note, however, that I normally dock with the laptop closed and leave the laptop's monitor while docked; that is, I don't expand the desktop to two monitors at the same time; if anything, it's mirroring or just one monitor on and the other off)
- https://superuser.com/a/176893/183485
- https://superuser.com/questions/297819/move-window-to-another-monitor-in-ubuntu-using-keyboard
- **https://askubuntu.com/a/195201/16023** <<< < < < *nota bene !* < < < <<<
- [How to move all windows to another workspace](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470324/how-to-move-all-windows-to-another-workspace)
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl

Comment: I haven't yet tried http://askubuntu.com/questions/6422/how-to-distribute-windows-over-virtual-desktops-in-gnome or http://askubuntu.com/questions/102616/is-it-possible-to-pin-programs-to-specific-workspaces-without-ccsm?rq=1 but both would constitute more of a work-around than a real fix for what may be considered a bug...

Comment: I might have to edit the question (again): it's not necessarily just one workspace on which all applications land on; rather, it sometimes (?) also happens that some applications land on one workspace, others on another. The bottom line: there's significant workspace <-> application re-shuffling...

Comment: Heya, have you managed to find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the exact same issue (Lenovo ThinkPad with docking station, running Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.5 LTS).

Comment: @KostaKontos no, unfortunately... :-/

Comment: Hi, nutty, how are you currently rearranging the windows, manually or by script? Also, is there a change in monitor setup when docked?

Comment: @user72216 No script, just "compiz / unity / ccsm" and standard keyboard shortcuts. No change in monitor setup (4:3).